# WPF Image not displayed after rotation transformation

Tags: c#, wpf, image, height, width

I am wondering if someone might be able to help me solve a display issue. I want to simply allow for a clockwise rotation 90 degrees using the code below:

```
        RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
        rotateTransform.CenterX = image1.Width / 2.0;
        rotateTransform.CenterY = image1.Height / 2.0;
         cW+= 90;

        rotateTransform.Angle = cW;

        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        transformGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform);


        image1.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
```

In XAML, when I define the image height and width, the image WILL rotate. However, when set to auto the image disappears after this code is executed. Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to use the image's `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth`:

```
RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
rotateTransform.CenterX = image1.ActualWidth / 2.0;
rotateTransform.CenterY = image1.ActualHeight / 2.0;
```

If you set the height and width explicitly, then these are the same.  When it's unset, the Height and Width arne't set, so your center is wrong.

Comment: Ahh, Thank you very much. I have been researching this for a couple hours and it was the simplest thing!

Comment: @Reed Copsey: how to set height and width explicitly after transformation?

Comment: @Dev You want the post-transform'ed height/width to be set?  You'd have to compute it, in that case, and set the width/height first.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: I have asked question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565828/set-height-and-width-of-image-after-transformation